# Layout resizing wrong when keyboard is shown

Tags: android

When I click in my edit text and my keyboard shows up, everything seems to be ok as in the picture bellow:

[image]

But when it has to shrink a little bit more my image is resized extending a invisible area, and my TextView still as big as in the begining, then my layout doesn't work anymore:

[image]

I've tried to create new images and dimensions for xhdpi resolution, but it didn't any effect

How can I fix it? How can I resize everything proportionaly. (I've tried to put a scrollview but i have a ListView inside my layout, as you can see in the code below)

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/login_background"
    android:descendantFocusability="beforeDescendants"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
    tools:context=".LoginActivity"
    android:id="@+id/fundoLogin" >

  <RelativeLayout
      android:id="@+id/relativeLayout2"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
      android:layout_centerVertical="true" >

      <ImageView
          android:id="@+id/image_login_fields"
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:layout_below="@+id/image_logo"
          android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
          android:contentDescription="@string/img_login_fields_desc"
          android:src="@drawable/login_fields">

      </ImageView>

      <ImageView
          android:id="@+id/image_logo"
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
          android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
          android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/margin_logo_to_fields"
          android:contentDescription="@string/img_logo_desc"
          android:src="@drawable/logo" />

          <TextView
              android:id="@+id/labelLogin"
              android:layout_width="wrap_content"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:layout_alignTop="@id/image_login_fields"
              android:layout_alignLeft="@id/image_login_fields"
              android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/margin_top_label_login"
              android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/margin_left_label_login"
              android:text="@string/login"
              android:textSize="@dimen/login_txt_size"
              />

          <EditText
              android:id="@+id/txtFieldLogin"
              android:layout_width="wrap_content"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/margin_left_txt_field_login"
              android:layout_alignTop="@id/image_login_fields"
              android:layout_toRightOf="@id/labelLogin"
              android:layout_alignRight="@id/image_login_fields"
              android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/margin_right_txt_field_login"
              android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/margin_top_txt_field_login"
              android:ems="10"
              android:textSize="@dimen/login_txt_size"
              android:hint="@string/txtFieldLoginHint"
              android:singleLine="true" >
          </EditText>

          <TextView
              android:id="@+id/labelSenha"
              android:layout_below="@id/labelLogin"
              android:layout_alignLeft="@id/image_login_fields"
              android:layout_width="wrap_content"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/margin_top_label_senha"
              android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/margin_left_label_senha"
              android:text="@string/senha"
              android:textSize="@dimen/senha_txt_size" />

          <EditText
              android:id="@+id/txtFieldSenha"
              android:layout_width="wrap_content"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:layout_below="@id/txtFieldLogin"
              android:layout_alignLeft="@id/txtFieldLogin"
              android:layout_alignRight="@id/txtFieldLogin"
              android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/margin_top_txt_field_senha"
              android:ems="10"
              android:hint="@string/txtFieldSenhaHint"
              android:singleLine="true"
              android:textSize="@dimen/senha_txt_size"></EditText>

          <ImageButton
              android:id="@+id/btnEntrar"
              android:layout_width="wrap_content"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:layout_alignRight="@id/image_login_fields"
              android:layout_alignBottom="@id/image_login_fields"
              android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/margin_right_btn_entrar"
              android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/margin_bottom_btn_entrar"
              android:background="@drawable/btn_entrar_clicked"
              android:contentDescription="@string/btn_entrar_desc"
              />

      <ListView
          android:id="@+id/listEmails"
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:layout_above="@id/image_login_fields"
          android:layout_alignRight="@id/image_login_fields"
          android:layout_alignLeft="@id/txtFieldLogin"
          android:background="@drawable/rounded_corner"
          android:visibility="invisible" >
      </ListView>

  </RelativeLayout>

   <Button
       android:id="@+id/btnTeste"
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
       android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
       android:textSize="@dimen/btn_teste_txt_size"
       android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/margin_right_btn_teste"
       android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/margin_bottom_btn_teste"
       android:text="@string/btnCredenciaisDeTesteTxt"
       android:textColor="@color/white" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you are looking for is the `android:windowSoftInputMode` attribute in the `AndroidManifest`.  This controls how your screen will respond to the keyboard being shown.  Right now it appears that it is using `adjustResize` and you want `adjustPan` so in your `Activity` declaration in the manifest add:

```
<activity android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"
```

You can read more about your options here:

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#wsoft

If you want the screen to resize you need to rethink your layout.

First, its bad form to have the login background as a separate ImageView.  Since you want it to resize you should create a 9 patch for the image at its smallest necessary size.  This makes the container define the size of the image, not the image itself.

Second, wrap your `TextViews` and `EditText` in a `RelativeLayout` alone then apply the 9 patch you created as the background of the `RelativeLayout`.  Now you will always have a login box that wraps your Views the way you designed it even when resized.

Comment: Acutually adjustPan is what I did for now, but it's not exactly what i want.